# Alert results that I got with JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json, api

Ok, i have the following. When the user puts something into the text field and then loses focus of it, an ajax-request is made.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//On Focus lose get content of the first input field
$('#fromCountry').blur(function()
{
    var input = $('#fromCountry').val();
    if(input == "")
        return false;
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'webservice.php',
                data: {country: input, action: 'firstTime'},
                success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    alert("TEST");
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
});
```

Then, it sends the request to the webservice with the country typed in into this field and the webservice uses a method from the database class to get the longitude and lattitude of that country (of the capitol of the country) and returns it as JSON

This is the webservice.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
require('Database.php');
$db = new Database();

$action = $_GET['action'];
if($action == 'firstTime')
{
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    $result = $db->getLocation($country);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

and this is the database class

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class Database {
private $user = "root";
private $pw = "";
public $pdo = null;

public function __construct($new = FALSE){
    try{
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=timezone',$this->user, $this->pw);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){

    }
}
public function __call($name, array $arguments) {

    if(method_exists($this->pdo, $name)){
        try{
            return call_user_func_array(array(&$this->pdo, $name), $arguments);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw new Exception('Database Error: "'.$name.'" does not exists');
        }
    }
}

function getLocation($country)
{
    $SQL = "SELECT cLat, cLon FROM countries WHERE cName = :cName";
    $prepare = $this->prepare($SQL);
    $prepare->bindParam(':cName', $country);
    $prepare->execute();
    $result = $prepare->fetch();
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

}

When I now type in Sweden for Example I get this as XHR response

```
array(2) {
  ["cLat"]=>
  string(10) "59.3333333"
  ["cLon"]=>
  string(5) "18.05"
}
```

which is basically right, but my ajax function doesn't alert "TEST" as it should because it is in the success function. Did I forgot to make one step?

----- EDIT:

I now added

```
,
                error: function(){
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
```

and it always goes into the error function, but why? I mean, it gets a response according to firebug, so where's the error?

Comment: Do you know what the HTTP code response was?

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
```

XMLHttpRequest is a class name and you can't name variables like that

Comment: hi, i changed it, but it still doesn't alert TEST. It somehow doesn't get into the success function. I now added `,
                    error: function(){
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }` and it goes into the error function, but why?

Comment: do you have firebug installed? check whats going on in its console. Possible you get some http error like 404 or 403

Comment: As I said the XHR of firebug tells me the code I posted above.